# No routes matching right location

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm creating a CRUD page to practice but I'm having trouble to get this to work. When I click the links they don't work. Nothing shows up on screen but the main CSS. Any suggestions?

```
import { Link, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Create from './Create'
import Read from './Read'
import Update from './Update'

const Crud = () => {
    return (
        <div className="bg-[url('/src/assets/hero-bg.jpg')] flex flex-col items-center h-screen p-16">
            <div className="container w-auto shadow-2xl rounded-lg p-8 bg-gradient-to-b from-emerald-500 to-emerald-900 font-bold">
                <h2 className="text-2xl pt-1 pb-10 text-white">Cadastro Cliente</h2>
                <div className="flex flex-row gap-5 text-black ">
                    <Link
                        className="p-2 border-b-2 border-r-2 rounded-lg bg-rose-400 hover:bg-rose-800 border-slate-600 shadow-lg"
                        to="/CRUD/Create">
                        Cadastro
                    </Link>
                    <Link
                        className="p-2 border-b-2 border-r-2 rounded-lg bg-rose-400 hover:bg-rose-800 border-slate-600 shadow-lg"
                        to="/CRUD/Read">
                        Consulta
                    </Link>
                    <Link
                        className="p-2 border-b-2 border-r-2 rounded-lg bg-rose-400 hover:bg-rose-800 border-slate-600 shadow-lg"
                        to="/CRUD/Update">
                        Edição
                    </Link>
                </div>
            </div>

            <Routes>
                <Route
                    path="/CRUD/Create"
                    element={<Create />}
                />
                <Route
                    path="/CRUD/Read"
                    element={<Read />}
                />
                <Route
                    path="/CRUD/Update"
                    element={<Update />}
                />
            </Routes>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Crud
```

When clicking the links it shows up the error 'No routes matched location "/Create"' and the same for the other 2 links. I really don't know what to do now since the path looks right.